# Angular Error while populating an object using map

Tags: angular

I need to populate document object of the following type. I am using Angular 7 typescript.I am not sure what the problem is ?

```
export interface IDocumentUpload {
    fileDropEntry: NgxFileDropEntry;
    name: string;
    selectedDocumentItem: { 'Id': number; 'Name': string; }
    selectedDate: Date;

}

    export interface IDocumentDetails {
        name: string;
        file: any;
        documentTypeId: number;
        documentDate: Date;
    }


    export interface IDocuments {
        managerStrategyId: number;
        documentDetails: IDocumentDetails[];
    }

    documents: IDocuments;
    public files: IDocumentUpload[] = [];
```

I am getting error

```
Type '{ managerStrategyId: any; 
     documentDetails: { file: FileSystemEntry; documentTypeId: number; name: string; 
     documentDate: Date; }; }[]' is missing the following properties from 
     type 'IDocuments': managerStrategyId, documentDetails
```

Code

```
    this.documents = this.files.map(doc => {
            return {
                managerStrategyId: this.ManagerStrategyId,
                documentDetails: {
                    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                    name: doc.name,
                    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                }

            };
        });
```

Updated JSOn based on Tom Tran's suggestion

Though the error went the structure of my json is

```
[{"managerStrategyId":7079,"documentDetails":[{"file":{"name":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"documentTypeId":null,"name":"Simplex - Copy - Copy.xlsx","documentDate":"2019-07-04T17:13:42.350Z"}]},{"managerStrategyId":7079,"documentDetails":[{"file":{"name":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"documentTypeId":null,"name":"Simplex - Copy (2).xlsx","documentDate":"2019-07-04T17:13:42.350Z"}]},{"managerStrategyId":7079,"documentDetails":[{"file":{"name":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","isDirectory":false,"isFile":true},"documentTypeId":null,"name":"Simplex - Copy.xlsx","documentDate":"2019-07-04T17:13:42.350Z"}]}]
```

Comment: Since `documentDetails` is an array, you're going to have to give it an array, rather than just an object like you are now. Try just wrapping your object in square brackets to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your type `IDocuments` (that is the type of `documents: IDocuments`) contains an array of `IDocumentDetails`.

```
    export interface IDocuments {
        managerStrategyId: number;
        documentDetails: IDocumentDetails[];
    }
```

Therefore, you need some how to map `documentDetails` as an array, not a single object.

So, (assuming I'm not sure about the business rule here, just try to resolve the error), solution is either:

- Correcting your mapping to make documentDetails as an array:

```
    this.documents = this.files.map(doc => {
        return {
            managerStrategyId: this.ManagerStrategyId,
            documentDetails: [{
                file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                name: doc.name,
                documentDate: doc.selectedDate
            }]
        };
    });
```

(notice the square bracket: documentDetails: **[{**...**}]**)

or:

- Changing your type definition for `documentDetails` to single object:

```
    export interface IDocuments {
        managerStrategyId: number;
        documentDetails: IDocumentDetails;
    }
```

**Updated:**

One more issue, you are mapping from the array of IDocumentUpload (`files: IDocumentUpload[]`) so probably you also need to define your `documents` as an array:

```
documents: IDocuments[];
```

(you can't map an array into a single object - cause mapping tackles on every object of an array and produces a new mapped object - 1-1 relationship)

**Updated to have only one managerStrategyId and the entire array of documents:**

Put it simple:

Keep your definition as the initial:

```
 export interface IDocuments {
        managerStrategyId: number;
        documentDetails: IDocumentDetails[];
    }
```

**<< First step: map your files (array) to documents (array)**

```
-  let documents = this.files.map(doc => {
            return 
                 {
                    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                    name: doc.name,
                    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                };
        });
```

**<< Second step:**

```
this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.managerStrategyId; and set
this.documents.documentDetails = documents (mapped array above)
```

Comment: When i tried the first i am getting error Type '{ managerStrategyId: any; documentDetails: { file: FileSystemEntry; documentTypeId: number; name: string; documentDate: Date; }[]; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'IDocuments': managerStrategyId, documentDetails

Comment: I tried the your updated suggestion. The structure of my json is incorrect. I have updated the post

Comment: Put it simple:

Keep your definition as the initial.

<< First step: map your files (array) to documents (array)
-  let documents = this.files.map(doc => {
            return 
                 {
                    file: doc.fileDropEntry.fileEntry,
                    documentTypeId: doc.selectedDocumentItem.Id,
                    name: doc.name,
                    documentDate: doc.selectedDate
                };
        });
<< Second step: this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.managerStrategyId; and set
 this.documents.documentDetails = documents (mapped array above)

Comment: Hi Tom, the first step is giving me a syntax error . Is it because of let document

Comment: I put the square brackets and the error is gone. The second step is complaining this.documents.documentDetails is undefined. Basically documentDetails is undefined

Comment: Even if I comment the the code where i am assigning douments , i get runtime error Cannot set property 'managerStrategyId' of undefined on line  this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.ManagerStrategyId;

Comment: Yeah am sorry that you need to init the this.documents first. Can do this.documents = {};

Comment: I am getting error Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'IDocumentDetails[]'

Comment: this.documents = {managerStrategyId : 0, documentDetails: null};
            this.documents.managerStrategyId =  this.ManagerStrategyId;
            this.documents.documentDetails = documents;

Comment: documents returns void[]

Comment: If I do this   const documents: IDocumentDetails[] = this.files.map(doc => { then I get the same error complaining at this line

Comment: Can you use let instead of const? And can you post your complete steps’ detail?

Answer (score 0):

Your this.files is an array so you cant map to object like this. Try this to see if it work

```
 this.documents =  this.files.reduce((obj: IDocuments, item) => {
          return {
            ...obj,
            documentDetails: obj.documentDetails,
            managerStrategyId: 1
          }
        }, {})  as IDocuments
```

Comment: I tried the exact code you gave and my JSON output s {"managerStrategyId":5412}

Comment: Not sure how to the documentDetails can get initialized automatically